# Tychonoff principle iff Wellordering principle

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Tychonoff Principle: Let $X_i$ for $i\in I$ be any sequence of non-empty sets indexed by the set $I$. Then the direct product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is not empty, where $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ is defined to be $\prod_{i\in I}X_i=\{f\mid Func(f)\wedge dom(f)=I\wedge\forall i\in I(f(i)\in X_i)\}$

Wellordering principle (WP) Let $X$ be a set then there is a wellordering $R$ of $X$

Prove that the Wellordering Principle (WP) implies, and is implied by the Tychonoff property.

Comment: The Tychonoff principle is _very_ similar in spirit, not to the well-ordering principle, but another famous axiom that is often mentioned in the same breath.

Comment: What do you know about the well-ordering principle by now?

Comment: For any set $X$ there exists a wellordering for $X$ and $(X,\prec)$ is a wellordering if it is a strict total ordering and for any subset $Y\subseteq X$, if $Y\neq\varnothing$, then $Y$ has a $\prec$-least element

Comment: I didn't ask what *is* the well-ordering principle. I asked what do you know about it. Do you know it is equivalent to the axiom of choice? Do you know it implies Zorn's lemma? Do you know it can help you avoid cleaning up your desk? What sort of corollaries and theorems do you know related to the well-ordering principle?

Comment: @Asaf: I don’t know about you, but I never had any trouble avoiding cleaning up my desk just in $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: @Brian: You should visit Shelah's office at some point. There is a pile of things there which can only be well-ordered using the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Yes, didn't know what you meant, $WP\Leftrightarrow AC\Leftrightarrow ZL$ understand these terms and that they are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that the well-ordering principle is equivalent to the axiom of choice, it suffices to show that the Tychonoff principle is equivalent to the axiom of choice.

**HINT:** Look at the definition of $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ and at the definition of a choice function for $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$.